# spark how can I ensure that all the messages are written to kafka and then only offset is set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to understand spark-kafka integration and have written a sample job that does the following:

- Read the values from PostGreSQL DB from a given timestamp.
- Write the data to the kafka.
- Write the latest timestamp to the PostGreSQL so that during the next execution this timestamp is considered.

Code:

```
package com.r2d2.spark.db

import java.sql.{DriverManager, ResultSet}
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

object TestJob extends App {

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[3]").appName("TestData").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_json, struct, col, lit, max}

val createDF = 
spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/analytics")
.option("user", "test")
.option("password", "test")
.option("query", "select key, value from test.sample_table_2 where updated_at >= (select updated_at from test.sample_table order by updated_at desc 1) order by id desc limit 2")
.load()

createDF.selectExpr("CAST(uid AS STRING) AS key", "CAST(value AS STRING) AS value")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "test2")
  .save()

val date = createDF.agg(max("updated_at")).alias("updated_at").collect()
.map(_.getTimestamp(0)).mkString

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/analytics", 
"test", "test")
connection.setAutoCommit(true)
val statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.execute(s"update test.sample_table set updated_at = '${date}' where id = 1")
}
```

My question is if in the middle of writing to Kafka if Kafka cluster goes down then will half of the messages get written to Kafka or it is either all or none.

Basically I want to ensure that all the messages are written to Kafka and then only timestamp is updated in the db.

Comment: Why not use Debezium to get data from Postgres to Kafka?

Comment: @ricket_007 Debezium is not an option for us.

Comment: How about Kafka Connect JDBC? In any case, I don't think Structured  Streaming gives you low-level access to the offset commit API like DStream would

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for taking an interest. I have explored a few options like  Debezium and Kafka Connect JDBC but we are inclined of doing it via Spark. I am new to Spark and trying to explore.

Comment: I'm confused, then. You have Kafka, therefore you have Kafka Connect. But you need to use Spark, although you're new to either one and one already solves the problem you're trying to write?

Comment: @cricket_007 The reason is we want to use the same solution for Greenplum and both Debezium and Kafka Connect JDBC don't have the support for it.

Comment: Umm... https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/streaming-server/1-3/kafka/load-from-kafka-example.html

Comment: thanks again for your interest, I really appreciate it. While Pivotal has something to get data into Greenplum but nothing to push data from Greenplum to Kafka

Comment: Your question says Postgres. I'm still confused why Kafka JDBC source connector would not work. You can don't need a Spark cluster or any cluster to make it work... But like I said Structured Streaming doesn't expose offset commits https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/24613